# How do I load a test file onto the SDCard using Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-device-monitor

I'm trying to test code that reads from a file on an SDCard.  To do that I'd like to load an example file onto my emulator's SDCard.  I believe I can do that with Android Device Monitor by pushing the file to the emulated device's folder, but which one ?  I appear to be able to put files onto the emulated SDcard and see them on the emulator settings \ storage and USB \ SD card, but my code reports file not found.  Any suggestions please ?  I'm using Android studio v2.3.1 on a Mac.  Here's my code :

```
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(dir,"dtcontrol.xml");

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

My manifest has permissions which I believe will give me access to the SD card :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
etc....
```

Comment: Are you trying it in an Android version 6.0 (API 23) or upper?

Comment: Hi, yes it's Android 6, API23

Comment: I added an answer to your question, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You must check for runtime permissions which where added in Android 6.0, now isn't enough to ask permission when installing the app.

It is very easy, before trying to load the DB file, you must check for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, if they are granted you can continue. In the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) you have more info on how to check and request runtime permission.

Other approach would be to create an `Android Virtual Device` with an API lower than 23 in order to test your code without having to add runtime permission, but then before publishing you should add them.

Comment: Hey thanks.  I've added  a runtime permission check to my app main for the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and I can see that I'm getting '0' ( PERMISSION_GRANTED ) back.  However, I still get a File Not Found IOException when I attempt to open the file.  From ADM's point of view, where should I put my test file ?  Thanks

Comment: So probably the problem is with the file path. Print your path from the `file` variable with `file.getAbsolutePath();` and check that it matches with the place where you stored the file. I can't tell you the exact path because it is usually different under certain conditions.